# How do I automatically include outDir when importing a TypeScript project?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I have a TypeScript library that uses a pretty standard src+dist setup in `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "rootDir": "./src/",      
    "outDir": "./dist/",  
}
```

When I compile this project and import it into another project, I can't import *.ts files in subdirectories without including "dist":

```
import { xyz } from "library/subdirectory/file"; //fails
import { xyz } from "library/dist/subdirectory/file"; //succeeds
```

What's the best way to automatically infer the dist directory? I was able to get the root by using the main attribute in package.json, but that doesn't help me get subdirectories and other files.